# how to run a kafka broker start script in background using ansible

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ansible, apache-kafka

How to run a Kafka broker start script written in ansible in background
when I am running it normally it is executing on the foreground and I'm unable to get back the control of terminal, if I close the terminal or Ctrl+c them Kafka broker will be stopped

My goal is after starting Kafka broker on the CLI, I need to run few more commands on that terminal to do some other tasks

```
ansible kafkabrokers -a "~/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/server.properties "
```

nohup and '&' are notworking

Comment: Would you please try the shell module: add `-m shell` option? It can support   pipe, nohup and &.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well I searched and found an answer for this is to use -daemon

```
ansible kafkabrokers -a  " ~/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon ~/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/server.properties "
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start the kafka in new screen, and detach screen once started.(keep running in background even you close the ssh session)

Please refer to screen command for details.